# How to tunnel host traffic through guest in Virtualbox using Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, tunnel

I have a Ubuntu host and an Ubuntu guest. I want to achieve that my host traffic is tunnelled through my guest. Thus enabling me to do analysis on the host traffic from the guest. I am assigning two interfaces to the guest (in addition to the built in NAT interface which is provided by Vagrant). I am creating a bridge interface on the host called br0. One of the guest interfaces is connected via bridging to eth0 (the host interface which is connected to the Internet) and the other guest interface is connected via bridging to the host br0 interface. On the host I am deleting my default gateway and adding a new one with:

```
route del default
route add default dev br0
```

After that I can vagrant ssh into my guest and set up a bridge interface there as well with.

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth1
brctl addif br0 eth2
```

After this setup the host traffic should be routed through the guest. If I run

```
tcpdump -vni br0
```

inside the guest I can see packets but I can't connect to the Internet. There is something missing. Any ideas?

Comment: have you enabled ipv4 forwarding on the guest?

Comment: Awesome. It would be great if you can update your original question or add the solution as new answer and mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable IPv4 forwarding in the guest.

Edit /etc/sysctl.conf to enable forwarding permanently:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Run this to activate the setting without a reboot:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```